# Unable to merge 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

```
echo $existing_data;

echo $current_data;

array_merge($existing_data->original, $current_data->original);
array_merge($existing_data->large, $current_data->large);
array_merge($existing_data->small, $current_data->small);

echo $existing_data;
```

**The Output is:**

```
"existing": {
    "original": [],
    "small": [],
    "large": [],
    "preview": {
      "name": "",
      "path": "",
      "reference": ""
    }
}

"current": {
    "original": [
      {
        "name": "TQT_82560100_1385618474_9480",
        "created_timestamp": "2013-11-28 06:01:14",
      }
    ],
    "small": [
      {
        "name": "TQT_82560100_1385618474_9480_small",
        "created_timestamp": "2013-11-28 06:01:15",
      }a
    ],
    "large": [
      {
        "name": "TQT_82560100_1385618474_9480_large",
        "created_timestamp": "2013-11-28 06:01:15",
      }
    ],
    "preview": {
      "name": "TQT_82560100_1385618474_9480_prev",
      "path": "images/",
      "reference": 0,
      "width": 137,
      "height": 137
    }
}

"existing": {
    "original": [],
    "small": [],
    "large": [],
    "preview": {
      "name": "",
      "path": "",
      "reference": ""
    }
}
```

I tried `array_merge_recursive()` too. But the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to save the result of an array merge

```
$result = array_merge($existing_data->original, $current_data->original);
```

example of php docs

```
<?php
   $array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
   $array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
   $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
   print_r($result);
?>
```

> Array (
>       [color] => green
>       [0] => 2
>       [1] => 4
>       [2] => a
>       [3] => b
>       [shape] => trapezoid
>       [4] => 4 )

Answer (score 1):

try to do like this-

```
$array1 = $existing_data->original + $current_data->original;
$array2 = $existing_data->large + $current_data->large;
$array3 = $existing_data->small + $current_data->small;
```